how to send a push notification using flask-socketio
I want to send notifications even to offline users in Flask-socketio through their browsers.
I am making a web-based chat application using flask-socketio, I want to send notifications to users via their browser so that they can get notifications for new chats even when they are offline to web app.

Very interesting that you are trying to send a notification to a client that is offline and does not have an established connection to the server. Good luck with the implementation. If you've found a way, let us know. We would be interested in your code.

@Detlef Actually I have done this in one of my previous projects but I am unable to find the code. Where I registered the browser of the user and then send a request to the browser which sends the notification.
